# Why does adb have a high CPU usage?

Tags: android, cpu-usage, adb

I'm using my T61 laptop to develop Android applications. Starting the debug bridge's server with `adb start-server` does create a process which runs at 100% CPU, see the output of ps:

`stephan  19837 99.3  0.0  19952   908 pts/0    Sl   13:50   3:42 adb fork-server server`

This is annoying especially since eclipse with the ADT plugin automatically starts this server (and the same problem occurs). I'm running Ubuntu Natty, but the same occurred also under Maverick and Debian sid. I'm sure that this problem did not occur after Ubuntu was freshly installed on the laptop, but started after a few days. What I noticed is also that adb fails to recognize devices that are connected to the computer while adb is running. If I restart the server with the not recognized device it is recognized after the restart. Maybe this is related?

As I said, it is installed on a T61 Laptop, using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty 64bit and 32bit with kernel 2.6.38-8-generic, but it also occurred on Ubuntu 10.10 32bit with the most recent PAE kernel, and on Linux Mint 10 64bit with the same(?) kernel version, and on aptosid 64bit with also some 2.6.38 kernel. Devices I use for testing are the G1, the Nexus (1) and a Samsung Spica. It is independent on which device is connected. My udev rules have been modified such that these devices are chmoded correctly. I have also a desktop machine with Ubuntu 10.10 64bit running, where this does not occur.

[In this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4318) it was claimed (a) that a kernel version change did solve this issue, that didn't work for me, and (b) a procedure requiring root access to the device. I'd like to solve this without rooting my phone, especially since this appears with multiple different phone models connected to the computer.

---

**Edit:** Please note that I don't have that laptop anymore and I couldn't solve the problem until I got rid of it. On my new computer the problem does not occur. Therefore I cannot check any solutions upon their validity and, thus, cannot mark a solution as accepted. (Should I close this question? Or what is the preferred way on StackOverflow to handle such a situation?)

Comment: Just did a fresh install of adb on Ubuntu 10.04 running on a 64-bit Macbook. Same problem...after 6 months...

Answer (score 1):

I was still facing this issue and I figured it out the it was the firefox extension that caused the issue. Get the pid of adb process by

$ps aux | grep adb

Then get the actual executable details by

$ls -l /proc/$PID/exe

You will get the adb process details. In my case the output was.

prabhat@paradise ~ $ ls -l /proc/16695/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prabhat prabhat 0 Jan 24 21:02 /proc/16695/exe -> /home/prabhat/.mozilla/firefox/c05prhhc.dev-edition-default/extensions/adbhelper@mozilla.org/linux64/adb

I simply deleted the extensions folder as I am not using it currently...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on iMac 9,1 Ubuntu 10.10.

adb fork-server server keep one core of the cpu to 90-100%

No power/suspend/resume possible issue in my case.
I just started eclipse after a boot.

"Solved" with these steps:
Power off, start eclipse, plug-in device (or start emulator)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and work around it by rebooting until ADB works correctly.

I've noticed the following may make a difference:

- Plug-in your phone before starting eclipse (which in turn starts ADB).
- Power down your computer and leave it off for a minute rather than just rebooting.

For me, the problem often occurs if my computer fails to return from suspend. However, this is probably just because I never reboot my laptop (apple MBP) unless that happens. I just suspend and resume. I've found that suspend/resume is fine. This does not affect ADB.

I was also the one that posted the comment in that bug report about rolling back the kernel version. However, I posted another comment further down indicating that that made no difference. I must've just been lucky that time.

One other interesting point. I also have a desktop machine that never has this ADB problem. However, I am conservative with my updates on that machine, as I don't want this problem to occur there.

I would speculate that this could be a ACPI or power saving related bug in ubuntu/debian. I never suspend my desktop machine.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your reply, though I never use suspend/resume (because the laptop is permanently docked as the battery is broken), maybe I'll try booting with acpi turned off. I came to the conclusion that this must either have something to do with my hardware or some of the drivers for that hardware as I don't have that problem on another laptop (T400s, Ubuntu 11.04, 64bit) up to now.